# Implementing find function for key value pair map on top of a generic set

Tags: haskell

I have the following code (removing not relevant parts) trying to implement key value pair map on top of generic set class (`Setlike`)

```
class Setlike f where
....
getElem :: Ord a => a -> f a -> Maybe a
..... 


newtype KV k v = KV { kv :: (k,v) } 
type Map f k v = f (KV k v)
type ListMap k v = Map [] k v
type TreeMap k v = Map BST k v    


find :: (Setlike f, Ord k) => k -> Map f k v -> Maybe v
find k m  = Nothing  where res=(getElem k m) -- this is the  problem, for some reason  I  this dummy line of code does not work
```

I get this error when calling (`getElem k m`) from the `find` function  :

```
** error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: k ~ KV k v
      Expected type: f k
        Actual type: f (KV k v)
    * In the second argument of `getElem', namely `m'
      In the expression: (getElem k1 m)
      In an equation for `res': res = (getElem k1 m)
    * Relevant bindings include
        res :: Maybe k (bound at hw02.hs:206:30)
        m :: f (KV k v) (bound at hw02.hs:206:10)
        k1 :: k (bound at hw02.hs:206:7)
        find :: k -> f (KV k v) -> Maybe v (bound at hw02.hs:206:2)
    |
206 |  find k1 m  = Nothing  where res=(getElem k1 m)**
```

I thought it should work because `m :: f (KV k v)` and `find` has a `Setlike f` constraint.

Comment: I'm still new to Haskell, but are you sure about the way you have defined `find`? `find k m = Nothing where ...` seems just a function which always returns `Nothing`, regardless of `where ...`.

Comment: The `where` clause is what is triggering the type failure. This is a stripped-down program that mainly exhibits the type mismatch he is asking about.

Comment: I think I would prefer `data KV k v = KV k v` (or `data KV k v = KV { k :: k, v :: v }`) to this newtype-wrapper-around-tuple thing. It has essentially the same (maybe *exactly* the same?) runtime representation, but is syntactically a bit lighter, as programmers have just one constructor to contend with (`KV`), rather than two (`KV` and `(,)`). See also [`Arg`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg), which may already have the instances you care about with the behavior you care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
getElem k m
```

you have

```
getElem :: a -> f a        -> Maybe a
m       ::      f (KV k v)
k       :: k
```

The first two lines suggest that we should choose `a` to be `KV k v`, but the first and third suggest we should choose `a` to be just plain old `k`. These are in conflict.

One way to fix this would be to invent an arbitrary `v` to use for the lookup, as in

```
getElem (KV (k, undefined)) m
```

and cross your fingers that the implementation of `getElem` will ignore the `undefined` and return the correct associated value instead.

Comment: Yes that worked as my set does look up only by key (k). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `getElem` takes a key (of type `a`) and returns a value of type `Maybe a`. In your usage, you pass in a key of type `k` and expect a value of type `Maybe v` where `v` is distinct from type `k`.

In other words, your `Map` type is not set-like, since the input key results in a different type `v`.

Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to do, rather than how you are trying to do it, we might be able to help.

Comment: I want to build a map like interface on top of a set - I need to pull the elements from the set to serve  the find function in map.